# Power BI: Substracting from rows based on missing value in a matrix

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need help with the following calculation in Power BI:

I have the following Data:

| Product | Salesperson | Country | Overall Inventory | Sold Extension Pass | Forcast Sold Extension Pass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City Bike | Gina | Canada | 5400 | 232 | 400 |
| Mountain Bike | Gina | Canada | 2323 | 2800 | 3210 |
| City Bike | Gina | Italy | 5400 | 213 | 429 |
| Mountain Bike | Gina | Italy | 2323 | 1050 | 1100 |
| City Bike | Gina | USA | 5400 | 122 | 200 |
| Mountain Bike | Gina | USA | 2323 | 2150 | 2699 |
| City Bike | John | Canada | 4323 | 333 | 344 |
| Mountain Bike | John | Canada | 2133 | 442 | 688 |
| City Bike | John | USA | 4323 | 3300 | 4000 |
| Mountain Bike | John | USA | 2133 | 7300 | 8000 |
| City Bike | Mary | Italy | 2321 | 213 | 322 |
| Mountain Bike | Mary | Italy | 2312 | 600 | 800 |
| City Bike | Mary | USA | 2321 | 123 | 400 |
| Mountain Bike | Mary | Canada | 2312 | 442 | 600 |
| Mountain Bike | Mary | USA | 2312 | 600 | 760 |
| City Bike | Overall | Canada | 12044 | 565 | 744 |
| Mountain Bike | Overall | Canada | 6768 | 3684 | 4498 |
| City Bike | Overall | Italy | 12044 | 426 | 751 |
| Mountain Bike | Overall | Italy | 6768 | 1650 | 1900 |
| City Bike | Overall | USA | 12044 | 3545 | 4600 |
| Mountain Bike | Overall | USA | 6768 | 10050 | 11459 |

The final visual looks like this:

[image]

Each Sales Person posses a certain amount of inventory from each Product and they are selling subscription like passes (dummy data). Not every Sales person is selling each product in each country. For example Mary isn't selling City Bike in Canada but Mountain Bikes and John is not selling in Italy overall. There are also no rows for these scenarios in the data.

I want to calculate the percentage of the Overall sales to add into the matrix (**Sold Extension Pass/Overall Inventory** and **Forcast Sold Extension Pass/Overall Inventory**), ideally as a measure or calculated column, but I have to take into Account that some Sales Person might not sell in the country. For example City bike has an overall of 12044 pieces. But since Mary is not selling in Canada I have to substract her Amount (12044 - 2321). So the calculation for the Overall percentage for City Bike sold in Canada would be: **565/(12044-2321)**.

My question is, how can I do this with a measure or calculated column. Since there is no rows for missing values, I can't filter and even if I can how can I substract the rows? I would prefer not to use Power Query but would do if I have to. I tried it with Power Query and it makes problems for the Overall Inventory in the row (showing many different amounts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
    SoldExtension % = 
var selectedcountry = SELECTEDVALUE(ProductSales[Country])
var selectedproduct = SELECTEDVALUE(ProductSales[Product])

return SUM('ProductSales'[Sold Extension Pass])/
CALCULATE( sum('ProductSales'[Overall Inventory]),FILTER(ALL(ProductSales), ProductSales[Country] = selectedcountry && ProductSales[Product] = selectedproduct && ProductSales[Salesperson] <> "Overall"))
```

[image]